# An array accessible by 1 thread which can return the data requested by the other threads

Tags: c++, database, multithreading, performance, data-structures

I have arrays stored in a dynamic unordered_map.
There is a write thread (it updates the tables with data received via WebSocket, REST, and others) and 1 read thread. (sometimes there can be 3 or 4 reading threads but this is rarer).
Currently, I have to lock all the unordered_map to be able to update or read data, so the parallelism is very limited.

I thought of another implementation that would allow me to not do any locks:

Have 1 single "database" thread which will be the only one able to access the data.
The thread will have a queue to receive requests from other threads: update, retrieve the values ​​of an array, have statistics on the number of messages received, etc.

My problem is that I don't know how to implement this to recover data.
Currently, the data is always copied to avoid holding a lock too long so I would continue to return copies.

I eliminated the choice of a callback function because the "database" thread should not be able to be blocked by another thread.

The number of write accesses / the number of reading accesses is 1000/1. About 400k write access and 400 reads / s.
Having to lock each write is therefore a real problem as access from other threads is really much rarer.
I would like to know if you have any ideas to implement this.

If you have any questions do not hesitate.

Comment: I'd suggest you to edit your question and provide some code.

Comment: @gst  What is the part that you did not understand and of which you would like an example?

Comment: Does the write thread update array elements or simply add new ones? Does the read thread remove something from the map or processes entire map? Do you really need a map, or is it a queue?

Comment: The writing thread will modify, add and remove array elements.
The reading thread does not modify any data, it just reads it. In most cases it will only access 1 single table contained in the map.
The map allows me to use id's to find the data more quickly.

Comment: So you have at least 3 threads, write that can't write, read that can't read and executer that can't block write (or only for a minimal of time)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize ***all*** access to the map, both reading and writing, because the internal data structures might be unstable *during* a write.  The "overhead" of this locking protocol is minimal, but unavoidable.

An easy way to do this is to coin an object which contains the *(private ...)* map and a private mutex.  Read and write methods are provided which give access to the map's data, using the mutex to serialize these.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm just trying to find a way to do it without using a lock.